# Translational Energy levels in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

One of the results arising from quantum mechanics is that energy is quantized for a particle. In particular, the translational energy levels are quantized.

- Is it fair to say that the translational energy levels of a macroscopic object are also quantized, but in such a way that the degree of separation between the energy levels is negligible ?

Additional Information:

My understanding of the translational energy of a particle is that, it can only occupy a discrete set of energy levels.

For example if we were to model the particle moving along the positive part of $x$ axis, its translational energy levels would be more akin to

$$f(x)=\lfloor{x} \rfloor$$ rather than $$f(x)=x$$.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: The energy of a free particle is *not* discrete, the spectrum of $H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ is completely continuous. You'll have to give more context for what you're talking about.

Comment: OK I shall clarify.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect; in general, energy is discrete for a bound particle, but continuous for a free one.

Comment: @Javier Thanks. This is probably a stupid question but what is the distinction between a bound particle and free one?

Comment: @J.Gudal: e.g. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/pbox.html#c3. Particles with energy $E>U_0$ are free particles, particles with $E<U_0$ are *bound* particles. For bound particles there has to be a *potential energy well*.